# java.util.date‘s value changed itself

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

when I startup tomcat , open a Jsp page with

`new java.util.date()`

at the beginning , date is correct ,like it

`date : Fri Mar 29 19:06:07 GMT 2013`

soon it changed to another value without timezone .

`date : Fri Mar 29 11:06:07 GMT 2013`

My server is linux centos6.4 , tomcat version is 7 ,jdk1.6 ,and server clock config is:

[image]

I modified my tomcat catalina.sh , add user zone :

`JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS $LOGGING_MANAGER -Duser.timezone=GMT+08"`

I doubt maybe my application has some bug , but what bugs can make `date` changes. I spent hours in this question and not resolved. any help will be greately appreciate.

Comment: the default timezone can be changed in java code.  make sure you don't have any code setting the default timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java's Calendar classes have ways of managing time zones.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
String monthString = calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.US);
```

There's also the `DateFormat` class to help you get a complete date string out of the calendar.